# Dragging down a median of 6 values in excel

Tags: excel

For the 6 values shown in the picture I want to find the median, but want to do that for each group of 6. Is there a function where i can drag it down and it correctly finds the median for each group of 6 without me having to do it manually each time? I tried it with the INDEX function like this:

```
=(MIN(INDEX($H:$H;(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6;0)-1)*6+2))+MAX(INDEX($H:$H;(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6;0)-1)*6+2)))/2
```

But that did not work properly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It appears you used one of the answers from your last question,  Please mark that one as correct by clicking the check mark by it.  It will reward the user and feedback like that is important.

Comment: Change both `INDEX($H:$H;(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6;0)-1)*6+2)` to `INDEX($H:$H;(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6;0)-1)*6+2):INDEX($H:$H;(ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6;0)-1)*6+7)`

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Thanks for your help and I have marked the answer as correct on the other question, but on this answer I cannot find the checkmark.

Comment: Would `=IF(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/6,0)=(ROW()-2)/6,MEDIAN(H2:H7),K1)` or `=IF(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/6,0)=(ROW()-2)/6,MEDIAN(H15:H20),"")` do what you are looking for?

Comment: As far as I understand the term **median** you would have to identify the one value in an ordered list of values, that is exactly in the middle. If the list is even, as in your case, you would calculate the average between the two values that are above and below that (non-existing) middle. Hence, @cybernatic.nomad is correct, by suggestion the usage of `MEDIAN`.

Comment: Good assesment, you are correct about the definition of median. I now realise I should rename that column, because I do want the value that is in the middle of the highest and the lowest value. I have tried searching for a name of this value, but I don't seem to find one.